# Need to bundle a bunch of .service files in deb package

Tags: deb, packaging, systemd

I am building a deb package (openstack-swift-account) and have dumped a bunch of service files in my `debian` directory.

I need to bundle all the `.service` files in my package but, by default, it picks only the one which matches the package name.

I tried to play around with `db_installinit`, but could not get it to work

```
override_dh_installinit:
    dh_installinit --no-start
    dh_installinit --no-start -popenstack-swift-account --name=openstack-swift-account-auditor
```

I have named my service file as openstack-swift-account.openstack-swift-account-auditor.service in debian folder. There are many others like these

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39576120/install-multiple-service-files-with-dh-systemd-packaging/39795036#comment72012286_39795036) :)

I posted the method in the comment over there, but I'll repeat here

Name the `.service` files as follows under the `debian` directory

```
<package1>.<service1>.service
<package1>.<service2>.service
<package2>.<service3>.service
... and so on
```

Then in `override` section

```
override_dh_installinit:
    dh_installinit -p<package1> --name=<service1>
    dh_installinit -p<package1> --name=<service2>
    dh_installinit -p<package2> --name=<service3>
```

The key is to not specify the `.service` extension in the `--name` parameter, provide the package name under which the file should be bundled as `-p<package-name>`, and name the `.service` as `<package-name>.<service-name>.service`